# Array only outputs last array initialized

Tags: java, arrays

I am having an issue with declaring and initializing object arrays within Java using jGrasp. This is an assignment and I copied the code straight from the book and changed the class and array name. I have tried assigning and initializing without an array by using 'itemA, itemB, itemC' with the same duplicate output as you can see at the bottom of the code.

**Driver class:**

```
class Driver
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        RetailItem[] item = new RetailItem[3];

        item[0] = new RetailItem("a", 1, 1);
        item[1] = new RetailItem("b", 2, 2);
        item[2] = new RetailItem("c", 3, 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
        {
           System.out.printf("item: " + item[i].getItemName());
        }
    }
```

The output results in:

> item: c
>
> item: c
>
> item: c

I do not understand as I am a beginner as to why the output is always the last array object initialized.

The output that I am attempting is:

> item: a
>
> item: b
>
> item: c

**Here is my RetailItem class:**

```
class RetailItem
{
    private static String itemName;
    private static int unitsOnHand;
    private static double priceEach;

    //Constructor(s)

    public RetailItem(String name, int qty, double price)
    {
        itemName = name;
        unitsOnHand = qty;
        priceEach = price;
    }

    //Public Methods
    public static double getPriceEach()
    {
        return priceEach;
    }

    public static String getItemName()
    {
        return itemName;
    }

    public static int getUnitsOnHand()
    {
        return unitsOnHand;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `static`? Why are you using it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: remove static from all the variable

Comment: Oh my goodness.. Works great now! I needed to remove 'static' from the methods as well for it to work. Thank you all for your quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `itemName` (and all your other variables) have been declared `static`. This binds them to the **class**, not to an *instance*, so when your constructor alters `itemName`, it alters that variable for the whole class.

To see what I mean by "class variable", try this: define a `main` method in `RetailItem` that looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print the property of the RetailItem *class*: remember, you don't even have an instance of the class at this point.
    System.out.println(RetailItem.itemName); // null

    RetailItem item = new RetailItem("a", 1, 1);

    // Print the property of the class again, ignoring the instance that you created.
    System.out.println(RetailItem.itemName); // "a"
}
```

To resolve this, just remove the `static` declaration from anything you intend to be an instance variable (as well as the setters/getters!).

```
private String itemName;
public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the itemName, unitsOnHand, and priceEach as `static`. Basically this means that all instances of RetailItem will have the same value for each of those variables. If you remove the `static` keyword each instance will have their own itemName, unisOnHand, and priceEach variables.